# knockout observables within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm going to try to explain this to the best of my ability. I have an object called `BaseForm` within that object I have functions and knockout observables. I have a function called `Initialize` that has an object within it filled with ko observables. One of the observables is called `FormVisible` and is initialized to true (`FormVisible: ko.observable(true)`). I also have a function called `OnClickRow`. In this function it changes `FormVisible` from true to false. I am instantiating `BaseForm` multiple times. When I call `OnClickRow` it only effects the last object that was instantiated. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
function BaseForm() {
  var that = this;
  BaseForm.prototype.Initialize = function(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.FormVM = {
      FormVisible: ko.observable(true)
    }
  }

  BaseForm.prototype.OnClickRow = function() {
    that.FormVM.FormVisible(false);
  }
}

this.base1 = new BaseForm();
this.base1.Initialize("new");

this.base2 = new BaseForm();
this.base2.Initialize("old");

this.base3 = new BaseForm();
this.base3.Initialize("other");

this.base1.OnClickRow();
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9onLoz20/1/).

Comment: You may find this helpful http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5147/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually figured it out. It's a pretty easy fix. I changed `this.FormVM` to `that.FormVM` and within `OnClickRow` I changed `that.FormVM.FormVisible(false);` to `this.FormVM.FormVisible(false)`. I'm still not enirely sure why this way works and why the other does not. So if anyone has an explanation, that would be great. Thanks!

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9onLoz20/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the prototype configuration outside of the constructor, and change 'that' to 'this':

```
function BaseForm() {
    var that = this;
}

BaseForm.prototype.Initialize = function(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.FormVM = {
        FormVisible: ko.observable(true)
    }
}

BaseForm.prototype.OnClickRow = function() {
    this.FormVM.FormVisible(false);
}
```

1. The prototype inheritance chain is called on 'new' or Object.create().  Therefore you should not declare prototype methods in the constructor because there's not guarantee that the prototype chain is initialized yet.
2. Moving these methods outside the constructor means 'that' would be undefined and using 'this' thus refers to the desired object.

I would suggest a review of the Mozilla Javascript documentation to enhance your knowledge on custom objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Custom_objects